# Linear combinations and spans

Tags: linear-algebra

So I'm trying to solve this problem but not sure how. Consider the vectors u=(1,2,3) and v=(2,3,1) in r3. Find k so that w=(1,k,4) is a linear combination of u and v.

I'm not sure what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry if format isn't correct, asking this from my tablet.

Comment: The problem isn't complete.

Comment: Rewrote the question as it appears in the book. @gitgud

Comment: You're being asked to find $\alpha, \beta ,k\in \mathbb R$ such that $\alpha u+\beta v=w$. This translates into the solving the system of equations $\begin{cases} \alpha +2\beta &=1\\ 2\alpha +3\beta &=k\\ 3\alpha +\beta &=4 \end{cases}$

Comment: I think you should re-read your definition of linear combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up the system of equations: $1=x+2y, k=2x+3y, 4=3x+y$.  Then, you have a system of linear equations with three equations and three variables and they are linearly independent so there is a solution.  What is the solution?

Comment: The answer is k = 11/5

Answer (score 1):

You look for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that
$$w=\alpha u+\beta v$$
so we find for the components:
$$1=\alpha+2\beta\quad;\quad k=2\alpha+3\beta\quad;\quad 4=3\alpha+\beta$$
now solve the first and the last equations for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and then you find $k$ in the second equality.